# Check is it link on email message clicked

Tags: html-email, email

I have website which send emails with links (not to the site url), I need to check if some link on email is clicked.
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: yes, you have the link point at YOUR site and then redirect the user to wherever the url should go. Otherwise, no, you can't watch what other people do in their browser. If it were possible, it'd be a massive invasion of privacy.

Comment: Thx, I know this way, but I was hoping there is another.

Comment: what other possibilities would there be? If there was some mechanism for a site/email to register itself for such spying activities, what makes you think that it would never get abused? Every spammer in the universe would be capturing every click from every user, without asking for permission.

Comment: Any third-party ESP (such as MailChimp or Campaign Monitor) provides basic click metrics on all links in an email, regardless of what site each link points to.